# NInject and thread-safety

Tags: multithreading, ninject

I am having problems with the following class in a multi-threaded environment:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Inject]
    public IBar InjectedBar { get; set; }
    public bool NonInjectedProp { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        /* The following line is causing a null-reference exception */
        InjectedBar.DoSomething();
    }

    public Foo(bool nonInjectedProp)
    {
         /* This line should inject the InjectedBar property */
         KernelContainer.Inject(this);
         NonInjectedProp = nonInjectedProp;
    }
}
```

This is a legacy class which is why I am using property rather than constructor injection.

Sometime when the DoSomething() is called the InjectedBar property is null. In a single-threaded application, everything runs fine.

How can this be occuring and how can I prevent it?

I am using NInject 2.0 without any extensions, although I have copied the KernelContainer from the NInject.Web project.

I have noticed a similar problem occurring in my web services. This problem is extremely intermittent and difficult to replicate.

Comment: What is your environment? i.e., are you hosting in WCF? What version of ninject? What extensions project are you using?

Comment: Can you replicate in a unit test?

Comment: NInject 2.0, no extensions. KernelContainer is the same as that in NInject.Web.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me say that this is wrong on so many levels; the `KernelContainer` was an infrastructure class kept *specifically* to work around certain limitations in the ASP.NET WebForms page lifecycle. It was never meant to be used in application code.  Using the Ninject kernel (or any DI container) as a service locator [is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

That being said, Ninject itself is definitely thread-safe because it's used to service parallel requests in ASP.NET all the time.  Wherever this `NullReferenceException` is coming from, it's got little if anything to do with Ninject.

I can think of two possibilities:

1. You have to initialize `KernelContainer.Kernel` somewhere, and *that* code might have a race condition. If something tries to use the `KernelContainer` before the kernel is fully initialized (possible if you use the `IKernel.Bind` methods instead of loading modules as per the guidance), you'll get errors like this.  Or:
2. It's your `IBar` implementation itself that has problems, and the `NullReferenceException` is happening somewhere inside the `DoSomething` method. You don't actually specify that `InjectedBar` is `null` when you get the exception, so that's a legitimate possibility here.

Just to narrow the field of possibilities, I'd eliminate the `KernelContainer` first. If you absolutely must use Ninject as a service locator due to a poorly-designed legacy architecture, then at least allow it to *create* the dependencies instead of relying on `Inject(this)`.  That is to say, whichever class or classes need to *create* your `Foo`, have *that* class call `kernel.Get<Foo>()`, and set up your kernel to `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()`.